# Proper way to implement/access a built-in page in my theme

Tags: pages

My theme has a top menu bar with accessibility shortcuts (jump to content, high contrast mode, etc). I need to include a link to an informational page describing the accessibility features available to visitors.

This is a project for an University multisite network, with a lot of hosted sites, so I need a solution that doesn't require manually creating the page on each site. I also want to be able to easily update this content on future versions of the theme (i.e., inserting the content in the database of several sites may not be a good idea).

I'm considering linking to the site's home page with some URL parameter, e.g. site1.example.com/?info=accessibility and addressing the content in the index.php, but that doesn't look too elegant.

Any advice on a cleaner way to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the following setup from reading your question:

site.network.com

site-2.network.com

site-3.network.com

where the main site exists on network.com (i.e. blog id `1`).
All sites (or at least all subdomain sites) share the same theme.

You need to be able to create a single content page and have that content available on all sites, i.e. *.network.com/some-page/

---

The below covers using a page on the main site (id 1) as the content source (allowing you to update/edit that content via the editor), and a template file for a matching page title.

You could include static content the same way. (see *Notes on Step 1* at the end).

---

### Step 1

You can add a page template to the theme for a specific page, say, named *Accessibility* by duplicating the *page.php* and renaming it *page-accessibility.php*

### Step 2

In *page-accessibility.php*, we will remove the normal loop, and replace it with some code to get a different page's content: the *Accessibility* page from the main site; using `switch_to_blog()`.

If the main site id is `1`, the template page *page-accessibility.php* might look something like this:

```
get_header(); 

switch_to_blog(1);
$post = get_page_by_title( 'Accessibility' );

if ($post) {
    $content    = do_shortcode( html_entity_decode( $post->post_content ) );
}
restore_current_blog();

?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php echo $content; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

### Step 3

Create an empty page named *Accessibility* for all sites. Rather than run something that would use `switch_to_blog()` to create a page for each one, we could instead check for the existence of the page on `init` of the site, and only create it if it doesn't exist.

*functions.php of theme*

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_default_page' );

function set_default_page() {

  check_exists_create_page( 'Accessibility' ); //again, checking by title
}


function check_exists_create_page( $title ) {

  if ( get_page_by_title( $title ) == NULL ) {

      $args = array(
              'post_title'      => $title,
              'post_content'    => '',
              'post_status'     => 'publish',
              'post_author'     => 1,
              'post_type'       => 'page'
        );

        wp_insert_post( $args ); 
  }

}
```

---

### Notes on Step 1

You could also use this [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to include static content. Remove the normal loop, and add your content directly or include another php file, etc. Then skip to Step 3 and create a page with a name that matches the *page-{your-page-name}.php* pattern for each site.

### Notes on Step 2

If you are wanting to use a site other than id`1`, you can always retrieve the id of the site you wish to use via [`get_current_blog_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id)

[`get_page_by_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) uses title **not** slug. To get a page titled *My New Page*:

`get_page_by_title( 'My New Page' )`

Here I am just linking more info on [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) and [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).
And for [`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog).

### Notes on Step 3

There may be a better hook than `init`. You could also add a conditional check if you wish to exclude some sites from this page check/creation. See my [answer on a different question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/275057/118366) if you need that.

Be aware during testing that a page in Trash still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive and didactical answer! I'll use the page template with my static content to keep everything contained inside the theme.

Answer (score 0):

If a plugin would work - see the WP Accessibility plugin. In Settings, 'Add Skiplinks' section, there's an option to add your own link (link or container ID). Could point to a central page?